# How to find offending Finder Extension?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, finder, error

I'm constantly (about every half second) getting this error on my MacBook Pro's console flooding my system log...

I've tried to kill all processes in hopes to find the offender, but no luck so far.

**Would anyone know how I can definitely find the exact Extension name? Is there a reference or command that will reveal such information?**

> Error details:
>
> 2016/01/08 13:55:50.398 FinderSyncExtension[1420]: assertion failed: 15C50:  libxpc.dylib + 35399 [61AB4610-9304-354C-9E9B-D57198AE9866]: 0x13
>
> 2016/01/08 13:55:50.398 FinderSyncExtension[1420]: failed to create remote port

Answer (score 8):

I found the offenders in my case (plural, for several apps were using this plugin), using a `ps -axe | grep FinderSyncExt` .

Before removing the apps using it from my `/Applications` folder, I decided to kill each of the processes using a `killall -9 FinderSyncExt`.

Answer (score 1):

After shutdown (*not reboot*) and cleanly booting up, I saw the system log show the name of the extension: odrive (www.Odrive.com).

I found an update for the extension and upgraded. This resolved my flooded system log issue.

Answer (score 1):

> FinderSyncExtension[1420]

I had a similar problem. I found that the number in the sqqare brackets is the process ID number of the offending process.

In your example, **ps ax 1420** should identify the process.

In my case, it turned out to be the Box Sync app.

Comment: I simply ran "console" from the home screen to see the system logs. Alternately, you could run this from terminal:

`tail /var/log/system.log`